# Leave pay - UK.

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

The company I worked for paid salary every 28th day of the month. This was my first job so I am uncertain about how much they would have to pay me after I left. I left on September 16th. Which means I was expecting at least more than half a month salary to be paid into my account plus the remuneration for the holidays not taken. However, the pay I received appears to be only associated with holidays not taken. I have been trying to contact an HR person who is responsible for these calculations for around two weeks to no avail. Is it correct, that I should have received at least half of the monthly salary, and if so where can I seek a legal advice?

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, if your official leaving date was the 16th, and you worked until the 16th, and you had lets say 4 days of holidays owed to you, you should get payment until the 16th, plus payment for the four days. Depending on how long you worked there, if they let you go instead of you quitting you might be owed more than that (statutory redundancy payment).

You should have been told on which day you receive that payment. I believe it should be on your official leaving date. And you should receive your P45 form, which should detail among other things exactly what salary you were paid, and what taxes were paid on your behalf. That should also happen as soon as possible, since you need the P45 for your next job.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually quit myself, so in that respect, they don't owe me anything, according to what you said. I have received my pay on the official salary payment day, which is 28th. But they only paid the days owed to me, which is like 3 days I think. I did not receive any salary up to 16th September and now they do not respond to any of my emails as I mentioned. What should be my course of action? (Neither did I receive p45)